# Rails.root - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a script located in `/bin` of a rails 5 project. Basically I am trying to iterate through various files and paths. Something to help me with this effort is `Rails.root` so I don't have to worry about relative paths etc

The problem is, when I am attempting to use `Rails.root` in my script, I am getting an error:

`uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)`

My script looks something like this

**bin/my_class.rb**

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    ...
  end

  def my_function
    ...
    Rails.root.to_s
  end 
end

MyClass.new.my_function
```

Then i call my script like

`ruby bin/template_check.rb foo=bar`

And it's breaking on the line where I am calling `Rails.root` with the error message:

`uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)`

I have tried

- moving Rails.root to a constant above the class (thought maybe it was a name conflict or something?). didn't work
- changing the name to `::Rails.root.to_s`. did not work either

Does anyone know why I cannot access `Rails.root` inside of my script?

**edit**
I was able to get this resolved by adding

`require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))`

to the top of my script. This loads rails. as a default, the script is slower, and I'm not a huge fan of loading all of rails just to use `Rails.root`, but for now it works.

Other solutions like the answers below are to either use `rails runner` to run the script, or to wrap everything in a rake task.

Comment: Perhaps because Rails isn't loaded when running `ruby bin/template_check.rb foo=bar`? Have you considered making it a `rake` task so that Rails is loaded?

Comment: @jvillian would definitely consider that. the person I am working with wanted a bin script because of how it is going to be used in the future. I was able to get this working by adding `require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))` to the top of the file. However, it did take a second to boot up so maybe there is a better way to approach this. I will keep the rake task option in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try with

rails r bin/my_class.rb  if your file is under bin
```

other wise you can use

rails r #{file_name}.rb specify the file name

Answer (score 0):

Run with `$ rails runner bin/my_class.rb`. You can find out more about rails runner [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner)